# Parsing a file by keywords

Tags: python, file, parsing

help with the parser of the file in python. There is a file with content:

```
============ | another peace mushroom enroll point trip sort notice hobby bacon exact slab | 0xb34a47885262f9d8673dc77de7b583961134f09fb03620b29d282c32ee6932be | 0xD0b2612a6eE3111114b43b25322C6F08A251D38D | Total: 47.62874464666479$ | | | Tokens eth: | 20.608732$ MANA | | Protocols cro: | 17.840052$ VVS Finance | 8.953779$ V3S Finance
============ | road vocal tissue faint wonder host forget canvas jump brisk latin trigger | 0x72e164aa187feaff7cb28a74b7ff800a0dfe916594c70f141069669e9df5a23b | 0xC7dFe558ed09F0f3b72eBb0A04e9d4e99af0bd0D | Total:
22.908481672796988$ | | | Tokens eth: | 22.376087$ SOS
============ | spend easy harsh benefit correct arch draft similar music car glad roof | 0xbce666bca3c862a2ee44651374f95aca677de16b4922c6d5e7d922cc0ac42a3d | 0x5870923a244f52fF2D119fbf5525421E32EC006e | Total: 9.077030269778557$ | | | Tokens eth: | 8.942218$ SOS
============
```

The separators in the strings are the characters ============ and I need to parse these strings, and output only the data between characters where Total is greater than 20. I will be grateful for help!
From the code I tried this option, but I need the remaining values between the signs === provided that Total is greater than 20.

```
with open('total.txt') as file:
    data_file = file.readlines()
    # print(data_file)

    for i in data_file:
        replace_data = i.strip('| ')
        replace_space = replace_data.strip('\n')
        remove_whitespace = replace_space.strip('\n')
        if 'Total:' in remove_whitespace:
            print(remove_whitespace)
```

there all the values on a new line, an example in the photo.[image]

Comment: The photo is your input file?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 1):

Consume the file line by line. If a line starts with '=' then you're starting a new section in which case you need to check the list of lines you've previously built up and also check to see if a Total was found greater than 20.

Try this:

```
outlist = []
flag = False
def dump(list_, flag_):
    if list_ and flag_:
        print('\n'.join(list_))
    return [], False
with open('total.txt') as file:
    for line in map(str.strip, file):
        if line.startswith('='):
            outlist, flag = dump(outlist, flag)
        else:
            tokens = line.split()
            if len(tokens) == 3 and tokens[1] == 'Total:':
                try:
                    flag = float(tokens[2][:-1]) > 20.0
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            outlist.append(line)
dump(outlist, flag)
```

Comment: super !
Just what I need, tell me how to write the result in the output.txt file?

Comment: @OlegPaslavskiy I think you'll find writing the output to a file trivial